# many buffers in char buffer

Tags: c, pointers, char, buffer, void

```
int main(int argc, char **args) {
    unsigned char* str = "hallo";
    printf("String: %s\n",str);
    uint8_t aktion, id;
    uint32_t str_length;
    aktion = 1;
    id = 4;
    str_length = strlen(str)+1;

    unsigned char *buff;    
    buff = (unsigned char*) calloc(1,str_length+6);
    memcpy(buff, &id, sizeof(id));
    memcpy(buff+sizeof(id), &str_length, sizeof(str_length));
    strcpy(buff+sizeof(id)+sizeof(str_length), str);
    printf("Buffer+5: %s\n",buff+5));
    memcpy(buff+sizeof(id)+sizeof(str_length)+str_length, &aktion, sizeof(aktion));
    return 0;
}
```

Why do i not get the output "hallo"? I am still unsure with using pointer arithmethics and buffers.

Regards

Comment: Given the way you cast the result of `calloc`, I assume this is C++. You should be using `std::string`, not mess around with naked pointers.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be casting the result of `calloc`.

Comment: Also, the naked `1` and `5` are weird. Why do you bother with the `sizeof` if you already know the size? Best though would be to write `sizeof` everywhere and not have magic numbers, and replace `sizeof(uint8_t)` with `sizeof id` etc.

Comment: Why, can you give me some background information? Omit the cast does not help.

Comment: No, it doesn't help, it's just better C. That's why it was a comment :-)

Comment: to be honest, it looks like some archaic spell, what are u trying to archieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint32_t str_length;
aktion = 1;
id = 4;
str_length = strlen(str)+1;

unsigned char *buff;    
buff = (unsigned char*) calloc(1,str_length);
```

you shouldn't cast the return pointer of malloc/calloc in C .

your `buff` size is 6

```
memcpy(buff, &id, sizeof(uint8_t));
```

you wrote 1 byte here

```
memcpy(buff+1, &str_length, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

you wrote 4 byte here :

which means you have exhausted 5 bytes out of 6 bytes allocated for `buff`

```
strcpy(buff+5, &str);
```

you are writting past the allocated bytes for buff . This would lead to **memory corruption**.

Comment: Ah okey the buffersize was wrong. Changed and now it workes! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
strcpy(buff + sizeof id + sizeof str_len, str);
/*                                        ^^^^   no '&'!  */
```

`str` is already a pointer. By contrast, `&str` is the *address* of the pointer, which isn't what you're after.

You will also need to make room in the buffer for the two initial variables.